# jquery.simplePagination.js:334 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentPage' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

Hello im getting this error in my browser, the function is working as intetend im just curious of why im getting this error, i can see that its becasue it sets the currentPage value to null but i dont understand why thats a problem. the paging works fine im just want to know if i can solved this error. im a rookie.

```
jquery.simplePagination.js:334 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentPage' of null
    at init._selectPage (jquery.simplePagination.js:334)
    at init.selectPage (jquery.simplePagination.js:66)
    at init.$.fn.pagination (jquery.simplePagination.js:389)
    at checkFragment (Blog:440)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Blog:447)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery.min.js:4)
```

---

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<script>
         // mind the slight change below, personal idea of best practices
         jQuery(function ($) {
             // consider adding an id to your table,
             // just incase a second table ever enters the picture..?
             var items = $("article");

             var numItems = items.length;
             var perPage = 2;

             // only show the first 2 (or "first per_page") items initially
             items.slice(perPage).hide();

             // now setup your pagination
             // you need that .pagination-page div before/after your table
             if (numItems > 2) {
                 $(".pagination-page").pagination({
                     items: numItems,
                     itemsOnPage: perPage,
                     cssStyle: "light-theme",
                     onPageClick: function (pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
                         // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
                         var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                         var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                         items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
                             .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
                     }
                 });
             }


             // EDIT: extra stuff to cover url fragments (i.e. #page-3)
             // https://github.com/bilalakil/bin/tree/master/simplepagination/page-fragment
             // is more thoroughly commented (to explain the regular expression)

             // we'll create a function to check the url fragment and change page
             // we're storing this function in a variable so we can reuse it
             var checkFragment = function () {
                 // if there's no hash, make sure we go to page 1
                 var hash = window.location.hash || "#page-1";

                 // we'll use regex to check the hash string
                 hash = hash.match(/^#page-(\d+)$/);

                 if (hash)
                     // the selectPage function is described in the documentation
                     // we've captured the page number in a regex group: (\d+)
                     $("#pagination").pagination("selectPage", parseInt(hash[1]));
             };

             // we'll call this function whenever the back/forward is pressed
             $(window).bind("popstate", checkFragment);

             // and we'll also call it to check right now!
             checkFragment();



         });
</script>
```

using:
http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

if anyone have a better solution for a foreach pagnation function please let me know.